# Using Jersey Client on port 443

Tags: httpclient, jersey

I want to configure jersey client to use port 443 when connecting to a web resource. I attempted to hard code the port in the resource locator but the client resorts back to port 80. I think this works automatically when using the HTTPUrlConnection but with HttpClient it appears you have to manually configure it.

Can soemone suggest how i might do this?

FYI - I have already tried this with httpClient Credential provider

```
httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(null, 443,null, "https"), creds);
```

And also

```
Scheme schemeHttps = new Scheme("https", SSLSocketFactory
                .getSocketFactory(), 443);
        client.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(schemeHttps);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with the proxy settings set in my Eclipse IDE. The IIS server could not recognize the "localhost" address so when i changed it to 127.0.0.1 it worked..